# Unable To Open Images and Video Using onActivityResult - Edited / Updated

Tags: java, android, image, video, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple task:

I need to be able to click the imageButton for video, select from gallery and play, and click the imageButton for images, select an image and view it - ALL USING THE GALLERY

How might this be accomplished?

I believe I'll need to modify my onActivityResult since it does not currently perform as expected.

### Current Source:

```
        ImageButton pb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photos);
        pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

        ImageButton vb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.video);
        vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
    .show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO);

            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*, image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"));  



            }

        }

        ;


    }
}
```

### Edit:

I have updated my source to reflect the most recent answer - however I am still unable to open images - I continue to get the "unable to play video" when attmempting to view an image.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkout this for video:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"), SELECT_VIDEO);

and this for images:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Images"), SELECT_PHOTO);


and in onActivityResult try this :

if (requestCode==SELECT_VIDEO) {

//take whatever video action

}else if(requestCode==SELECT_PHOTO){

//take whatever image action

}
```

Comment: When I try to select an image to view using the gallery I get a video related error msg stating "unable to play this video" when selecting an image : ( 

(any suggestions?) 

http://pastebin.com/zqcKupwU

Comment: I think something is getting mixed up in onActivityResult

Comment: I think you have to remove Intent.ACTION_PICK just create intent object like Intent intent=new Intent();

Comment: I updated my code as suggested - I still get the error stating "unable to play this video" when selecting an image: 

http://pastebin.com/DBtBFCav

Comment: I'm still not sure why Im getting a video related error when clicking an image...

Comment: Any other ideas / suggestions?

Comment: I have checked.Its working in my code.Please post your class file so i can check it.